# Unable to reach site after IIS upgrade: HTTPS 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: iis, https

I get this error when trying to access my site via HTTPS. HTTP works as expected. Had a server that failed and had to move from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.0 on Window Server 2008.  Was able to install my SSL, but am unable to reach it via HTTPS now.  ASP.NET site Framework 3.5. Would love any ideas on figuring this out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are dozens of things it could be. Can you post the output of the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application is configured to accept https.

[image]

You get to that window by clicking on your website on IIS Manager and selecting "Advanced Settings" on the `Actions` bar on the right hand side.